# How to put a spring web service online?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am completely new to web services. I am trying to learn Spring. I did the tutorial to implement a simple web service with spring as given in the following link [Spring Restful Web Service Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). It worked fine in localhost, but my question is how can I publish this web service on any hosting server? I mean with this, to access the web service over the internet with a URL instead of localhost!

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access your WebService over the internet, you need it to be hosted on a Java hosting provider. If you have a static IP, you can try to host it yourself although I would not recommend it.

You can do a quick google search for java web hosts if you want to find one, but they aren't usually free.

( See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606788/hosting-java-app-on-free-web-hosting-site) )

Answer (score 1):

The [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) you followed deployed the web service in embedded tomcat container in the same process in which the main program ran. This is usually very helpful for quick prototype to understand the concepts and working of the program but of course in real world you would need hosting provider for the server in which your web service would run.